# How to Implicitly get ParseUser's Write ACL

Tags: android, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

*implicitly* meaning considering the Roles the user is in, get me the write access for this user on this object, and my approaches are inefficient, I think:

1. Cloud code function for querying the user's roles then checking whether the user or his roles have right access to the object.

> ```
>   Parse.Cloud.define("hasWriteAccess", function(request, response){
>     var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
>     query.equalTo("users", request.user);
>     query.find().then(function(roles){
>       var hasWriteAccess = false;
>       for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
>         if (request.params.parseObject.getACL().getRoleWriteAccess(roles[i])) {
>           hasWriteAccess = true;
>           break;
>         }
>       }
>       response.success(hasWriteAccess);
>     });
>   });
> ```

2. Android user's roles query and locally checking write access

   ```
   public static Task<Boolean> hasWriteAccess(final ParseObject parseObject) {
       final TaskCompletionSource<Boolean> voidTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
       ParseRole.getQuery().whereEqualTo("users", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()).findInBackground().continueWith(new Continuation<List<ParseRole>, Object>() {
           @Override
           public Object then(Task<List<ParseRole>> task) throws Exception {
               if (task.getError() == null) {
                   List<ParseRole> parseRoles = task.getResult();
                   boolean hasWriteAccess = false;
                   for (ParseRole parseRole : parseRoles) {
                       if (parseObject.getACL().getRoleWriteAccess(parseRole)) {
                           hasWriteAccess = true;
                           break;
                       }
                   }
                   voidTaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(hasWriteAccess);
               } else {
                   voidTaskCompletionSource.trySetError(task.getError());
               }
               return null;
           }
       });
       return voidTaskCompletionSource.getTask();
   }
   ```

   from `Parse Documentation`

   - Get whether the given user id is *explicitly* allowed to write this object. Even if this
   - returns {@code false}, the user may still be able to write it if getPublicWriteAccess returns
   - {@code true} or a role that the user belongs to has write access.
     */

I can't use these methods on my main posts activity because they are slow `network requests`, and waiting for the request to finish before querying for the posts results in bad user experience.

This solution won't work because the query won't return the nested roles `roles relation`, So any suggestions?

Comment: In your cloud code, I bet `request.object.ParseObject...` is not what you expect it to be.  Maybe you meant `request.params.object`, assuming you're passing in a ParseObject to a param called `object` to your cloud function.

Comment: ooh, sorry this is just a typo here... but my question is about the way I'm getting the ACL, it won't work if roles are nested, what's the solution then?... I think my question is a little unclear